# Вывести внесенные данные из EditText в Activity Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, onclicklistener

Схема работает следующим образом:
Запускается активность, при клике на  EditText можно ввести данные в формате String, при нажатии на кнопку, назовем ее к примеру apply, сохраняются введенные данные
Необходимо реализовать это через обработчик ClickListner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну собственно:

```
button.setOnClickListener { 
    val text = editText.getText().toString() 
    // some logic with your text
}
```